# How does RDD coalesce work

Tags: apache-spark, r-sp

I know that RDD coalesce can be used to shrink RDD partitions `without shuffle` from bigger size to smaller size, for example, from 100 partitions to 10 partitions.

But I don't understand how `without shuffle` works, for example, I have 10 executors, and an RDD which has 10 partititons, each executor has 1 partition,If I shrink this RDD to 5 partitions, there must shuffle happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDD coalesce `doesn't do any shuffle` is incorrect it doesn't do full shuffle ,rather minimize the data movement across the nodes.

So it will do some shuffle but not the full shuffle which the repartition will do. With coalesce you can only decrease the number of partitions. If you want to increase it does the repartition itself.

There is a nice [blog](https://hackernoon.com/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4) explaining the issue

Comment: Thanks @avishek-bhattacharya for the great answer. But in the blog,  `The partitioning of DataFrames seems like a low level implementation detail that should be managed by the framework, but it’s not. When filtering large DataFrames into smaller ones, you should almost always repartition the data.` I think `always repartition`n the data should be `always coalesce the data`

Comment: hi @Avishek, the url in the ansert is not working anymore

Comment: Yeah looks like they have removed it. It was a nice blog.